# How will I get id in a4j:ajax oncomplete?

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I've faced to the issue with a4j:ajax component . How do I get id of the parent component in oncomplete function ?

I have rich:dataTable and all column is inputText with ajax listener , what I need to do is when ajax validation returns false then I need to focus on that field and change background to red. Unfortunately I don't know how to get Id of particular inputText from  tags.  The code below is telling what I'm going to do but the id of component is undefined . I guess because of this is id of ajax function not inputText...

This is the code:

```
<h:inputText value= "#{resultsTableRow[valueOfField]}" >
    <a4j:ajax event="blur" exceute="@form" render="submitManualsButton" 
    listener="#{bean.theActionListener(resultsTableRow.identifier , columnDBName)}" 
    oncomplete=" if (#{bean.validationResult}) #{rich:component('validationPopup')}.show();

   setFocusOnElement(this.id); // <----- that is crucial 


   return false;" />
</h:inputText>
```

And js function:

```
function setFocusOnElement( element)
{   
   $(resolveId(id)).focus();
}
```

Any help will be great! Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Well, give an id to the input and use that.

```
<h:inputText id="input" …>
    …
    setFocusOnElement("input");
```

Now, since the fullIds look different you'll need to do something like this:

```
<rich:dataTable rowKeyVar="rk" …>
    …
    <h:inputText id="input#{rk}" …>
        …
        setFocusOnElement("input#{rk}");

function setFocusOnElement(id)
{   
    $('[id$=' + id + ']').focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that probably will work ... But what in case I have multiple 5,6 inputs per Row?

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to determine the ids in the bean and then retrieve them. You can use the `data` attribute for that.